# I2C COMMUNICATION

Tags: microcontroller

one micro-controller support all adc dac, spi, uart except I2C, but i want to use i2c communication.How to make i2c port using these protocol?

Comment: There are multiple examples of libraries implementing an I2C port on GPIO. Do some research.

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you told us which microcontroller you are using, and whether you need your micro to be an I2C master, a slave, or either.

If you just need to an I2C master, and you don't need to worry about other masters on the same bus (arbitration) or very slow slave devices (clock stretching), then I2C is very simple to implement using two GPIO pins. Search for " software i2c master" and you'll find things like [I2C Implementation on 8051](http://www.8051projects.net/wiki/I2C_Implementation_on_8051).

If you need to do arbitration because there may be multiple masters on the bus, or if you need to handle slave clock stretching, then read the [I2C specification from <strike>Philips</strike> NXP](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10204.pdf). Take the simple code you find through Google and add the functionality you need.